# Set content function returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-6

I'm using this script to get the content of TinyMCE:

```
let editorContent;
editorContent.set(tinymce.get("firstEditor").getContent());
```

After receiving the content, I save it to my database as a string value.
When needed I want to be able to retrieve the value and display it in the same TinyMCE editor. I tried using the script below to do so but that ends up displaying [object Object]..

```
tinymce.get("firstEditor").setContent(editorContent);
```

Does anybody have some clue to what could cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I fount the solution, using ".get()" on the string variable worked!

So instead of:

```
tinymce.get("firstEditor").setContent(editorContent);
```

I used this command:

```
tinymce.get("firstEditor").setContent(editorContent.get());
```